# Error due to improper implementation of classes in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, object, oop

I wrote the following program, and have reached the following code finally as per my understanding. There
still seem to be a host of errors like:

1. `identifier "lambertian" is undefinedC/C++`  in text editor  -for lambertian in `auto material_ground = make_shared<lambertian>(color(0.8, 0.8, 0.0));`

2) `pointer to incomplete class type "material" is not allowed`   - for rec in
`if (rec.mat_ptr->scatter(r, rec, attenuation, scattered))` in editor

I'm also facing multiple errors in compilation like:

3. `vec3.h: In member function 'vec3 vec3::reflect(const vec3&, const vec3&)': vec3.h:61:33: error: 'dot' was not declared in this scope return v - 2*dot(v,n)*n;`
4. `invalid use of incomplete type 'class hittable_list' class hittable_list : public hittable_list`
5. `sphere.h:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided sphere.h:7:7: note: candidate: sphere::sphere(sphere&&)`

And I think I've most probably implemented classes improperly so, is there any resource that would help me avoid such errors in the near future?

Code:

chap_8.cpp:

```
    #include "camera.h"
#include "rtweekend.h"
#include "vec3.h"
#include "color.h"
#include "hittablelist.h"
#include "sphere.h"
#include "ray.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "material.h"
#include "hittable.h"

color ray_color(const ray& r, const hittable_list& world, int depth) {
    hit_record rec;

    // If we've exceeded the ray bounce limit, no more light is gathered.
    if (depth <= 0)
        return color(0,0,0);

    if (world.hit(r, 0.001, infinity, rec)) {
        ray scattered;
        color attenuation;
        if (rec.mat_ptr->scatter(r, rec, attenuation, scattered))
            return attenuation * ray_color(scattered, world, depth-1);
        return color(0,0,0);
    }

    vec3 unit_direction = unit_vector(r.direction());
    auto t = 0.5*(unit_direction.y() + 1.0);
    return (1.0-t)*color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) + t*color(0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
}



int main() {

    // Image

    const auto aspect_ratio = 16.0 / 9.0;
    const int image_width = 400;
    const int image_height = static_cast<int>(image_width / aspect_ratio);
    const int samples_per_pixel = 100;
    const int max_depth = 50;

    // World

    hittable_list world;
    auto material_ground = make_shared<lambertian>(color(0.8, 0.8, 0.0));
    auto material_center = make_shared<lambertian>(color(0.7, 0.3, 0.3));
    auto material_left   = make_shared<metal>(color(0.8, 0.8, 0.8), 0.3);
    auto material_right  = make_shared<metal>(color(0.8, 0.6, 0.2), 1.0);

    world.add(make_shared<sphere>(point3( 0.0, -100.5, -1.0), 100.0, material_ground));
    world.add(make_shared<sphere>(point3( 0.0,    0.0, -1.0),   0.5, material_center));
    world.add(make_shared<sphere>(point3(-1.0,    0.0, -1.0),   0.5, material_left));
    world.add(make_shared<sphere>(point3( 1.0,    0.0, -1.0),   0.5, material_right));

    // Camera

    camera cam;

    // Render

    std::cout << "P3\n" << image_width << " " << image_height << "\n255\n";

    for (int j = image_height-1; j >= 0; --j) {
        std::cerr << "\rScanlines remaining: " << j << ' ' << std::flush;
        for (int i = 0; i < image_width; ++i) {
            color pixel_color(0, 0, 0);
            for (int s = 0; s < samples_per_pixel; ++s) {
                auto u = (i + random_double()) / (image_width-1);
                auto v = (j + random_double()) / (image_height-1);
                ray r = cam.get_ray(u, v);
                pixel_color += ray_color(r, world, max_depth);
            }
            write_color(std::cout, pixel_color, samples_per_pixel);
        }
    }

    std::cerr << "\nDone.\n";
}
```

hittablelist.h

```
    #ifndef HITTABLE_LIST_H
#define HITTABLE_LIST_H

#include "hittable.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;

class hittable_list : public hittable_list {
    public:
        hittable_list() {}
        hittable_list(shared_ptr<hittable_list> object) { add(object); }

        void clear() { objects.clear(); }
        void add(shared_ptr<hittable_list> object) { objects.push_back(object); }

        virtual bool hit(
            const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec) const override;

    public:
        std::vector<shared_ptr<hittable_list>> objects;
};

bool hittable_list::hit(const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec) const {
    hit_record temp_rec;
    bool hit_anything = false;
    auto closest_so_far = t_max;

    for (const auto& object : objects) {
        if (object->hit(r, t_min, closest_so_far, temp_rec)) {
            hit_anything = true;
            closest_so_far = temp_rec.t;
            rec = temp_rec;
        }
    }

    return hit_anything;
}

#endif
```

sphere.h

```
  #ifndef SPHERE_H
#define SPHERE_H

#include "hittable.h"
#include "vec3.h"

class sphere : public hittable_list {
public:
    sphere() {}
    sphere(point3 cen, double r, shared_ptr<material> m)
        : center(cen), radius(r), mat_ptr(m) {};
    virtual bool hit(
        const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec) const override;

    public:
    point3 center;
    double radius;
    shared_ptr<material> mat_ptr;
    };

bool sphere::hit(const ray& r, double t_min, double t_max, hit_record& rec) const {
vec3 oc = r.origin() - center;
auto a = r.direction().length_squared();
auto half_b = dot(oc, r.direction());
auto c = oc.length_squared() - radius*radius;

auto discriminant = half_b*half_b - a*c;
if (discriminant < 0) return false;
auto sqrtd = sqrt(discriminant);

// Find the nearest root that lies in the acceptable range.
auto root = (-half_b - sqrtd) / a;
if (root < t_min || t_max < root) {
    root = (-half_b + sqrtd) / a;
    if (root < t_min || t_max < root)
        return false;
}

rec.t = root;
rec.p = r.at(rec.t);
vec3 outward_normal = (rec.p - center) / radius;
rec.set_face_normal(r, outward_normal);
rec.mat_ptr = mat_ptr;
return true;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], I think the error would become obvious by then. That's also the reason this is actually required! Also note that you shouldn't ask multiple questions in one. Fix each of your errors separately.

Comment: `class hittable_list : public hittable_list` – you don't see a problem here?

Comment: Also, "sphere.h" has `#include "hittable.h"`, not `#include "hittable_list.h"`, but `sphere` inherits `hittable_list`?

Comment: Drop the habit of writing all your code in headers. It quickly becomes a dependency-management nightmare.